# How can I just use MUI-Datatable without getting the whole material/core?

Tags: reactjs, antd, mui-datatable

I am using antdesign as the overall library of a react project, but I want to use the MUI-Datatable due to its better table and functionalities.

If there is no other way to do this, are there repercussions in using 2 whole libraries inside one react project?

Answer (score 0):

[MUI-Datatables](https://github.com/gregnb/mui-datatables/) is build on Material-UI (see its package.json [here](https://github.com/gregnb/mui-datatables/blob/master/package.json)). So it is not possible to use it without @material/core.